# Making tikzmark (or an alternative) work with tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter, tikzmark

I'm writing an academic poster using `tikzposter`. I'd like to draw arrows connecting different points of text (in the same block), and it seems that `tikzmark` would be a good option for this. However, the two don't play nicely together. Here's an MWE (using the first example from the `tikzmark` documentation).

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}

\begin{document}

\block{a block}{
\[
\tikzmark{a} e^{ i \pi /2} = i
\]

This \tikz [remember picture, overlay, baseline=0pt]
\draw[->] (0,1em) to [bend left]
([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}] pic cs:a) ; is an important equation.
}

\end{document}
```

Error message: `! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate`.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either `\pgfmark` or `\subnode` instead of `\tikzmark`.

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning}

\begin{document}

\block{using pgfmark}{
    \[
    \pgfmark{a} e^{ i \pi /2} = i
    \]

    This \tikz [remember picture, overlay, baseline=0pt]
    \draw[->] (0,1em) to [bend left]
    ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}] pic cs:a) ; is an important equation.
}

\block{Using subnode}{
    \[
    \subnode{b} e^{ i \pi /2} = i
    \]

    This \tikz [remember picture, overlay, baseline=0pt]
    \draw[->] (0,1em) to [bend left]
    ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}] pic cs:b) ; is an important equation.
}

\end{document}
```